# In matplotlib setting minor ylabel invisible fails after zoom in

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label

I creat a plot with major and minor y ticks. I set evry 5'th minor ticks invisible to avoid intereference of the major and minor ticks. It works fine when I creat my plot but after I zoom in it gets broken. I use python 2.7.11 with Canopy 1.7.4.3348 as IDE.

I creat ticks for the y axis as next:

1. major ticks are set for y = n +- 0.5 where n is element of Z, where Z labels integers
2. minor ticks are set for y = n +- 0.1 where n is element of Z, where Z labels integers
3. to avoid interferenc with the major ticks evry 5'th element of the minor ticks are set invisible

The code which implement this is the next:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
y = np.sin(x)

majorLocatorX  = MultipleLocator(0.5)
majorFormatterX = FormatStrFormatter('%.1f')

majorLocatorY  = MultipleLocator(0.5)
minorLocatorY  = MultipleLocator(0.1)
majorFormatterY = FormatStrFormatter('%.1f')
minorFormatterY = FormatStrFormatter('%.1f')

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\sin(x)$')
ax1.set_xlim([-0.03,2*np.pi+0.03])
ax1.set_ylim([-1.03,1.03])
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocatorX)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatterX)
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocatorX)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocatorY)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatterY)
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocatorY)
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(minorFormatterY)
for label in ax1_1.yaxis.get_ticklabels('minor')[1::5]:
    label.set_visible(False)
ax1.plot(x,y,label=r'$\sin(x)$')
ax1.legend(loc='best',fontsize=12.0)

plt.show()
```

Before I zoom in I have the plot:
[The "original" plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBnmu.png).

After I zoom in I get the plot:
[The zoomed in plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubk6R.png).

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: It is not broken. As can be seen the 5th minor ticklabel is still invisible after zooming. Can you be more clear on what the desired output is?

Comment: Yes. So on the "original" plot it is true that every 5'th minor tick label is invisible.  I would like that the same minor tick labels will not be visible also in case when I zoom in. So I basicaly would like to avoid the situation one can see on the "zoomed in" plot that the major tick labels are overwritten by the minor tick labels at places 0.0 and 0.5.

Comment: It *is* the same minor ticklabel that is still invisible. On the zoomed plot you would probably want the 7th minor ticklabel invisible instead.

Comment: Ok. I just defined my purpose probably poorly. I would like to be able to avoide the overwriting the major tick labels by the minor tick labels even if I zoom in. I probably don't realy understand how the ticks are functionating. Could you help me with a solution to reach my goal?

Comment: One problem I have with this question is that it is not clear to me what the rules are to decide where which ticks should be placed. Using `MultipleLocators` and zooming somehow seem contradictory since if you zoom further in or out you would loose all labels or just have them all cluttered.

Comment: There are actually no rules. I arbitrarily decided to locate the ticks as it was defined in my post. I would use such kind of methode for some scientific data analisys for which the placing of ticks can not be define before and for wich the automatic placing seems not to be satisfactory. Ps.: With a self defined appropriate placing there will be ticks after zooming in.